# How can I show Youtube feed in my Windows Store 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 app ? c#

Tags: c#, youtube, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

This is my windows phone app : http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/teknoseyir-v2-0/fd13b86d-5505-486b-8091-1ada54546d15

and this is my window store app: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/tr-tr/app/teknoseyir-v2-0/59e66213-4729-4091-97fa-9dc688892a25

This is a webview app . Source is teknoseyir.com ( Turkish Social Technology Network) Teknoseyir is sending their videos to youtube channel. I want to add button to appbar and navigate user to new page . Here is the problem , I want to show teknoseyir youtube feed in this new page.

I have found to add videos to hand by hand but I want to show channel feed automatically. How can I do this ?

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs.

Comment: I have just edit the question. You are right. Thanks. Yine de yardım etmek istersen çok memnun olurum Soner Abi .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet). It allows apps to retrieve and update YouTube content in the form of RSS feeds. Your  app can use the YouTube Data API to fetch video feeds, channels, and playlists for videos that match particular criteria.

You can find help in [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Youtube-Sample-Get-Youtube-e9a3e0be) Sample